# Parameter of Mat.at() in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm running a program to sample data from an image recently. The code:

```
cv::Mat image_data;
Eigen::Vector3f getColor(float u, float v)
    {
        auto u_img = u * width;
        auto v_img = (1 - v) * height;
        auto color = image_data.at<cv::Vec3b>(v_img, u_img);
        return Eigen::Vector3f(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
    }
```

When calling image_data.at(v_img, u_img),the program will throw an exception. And I find that v_img == 578.815 and u_img == -28.672,  and the size of image_data is 1024*1024. Is there anything wrong with the data?

Comment: `u_img == -28.672` Even if floating-point indices are allowed (which apparently they are), what do you think a negative index will do?

Comment: `cv::Mat::at` requires `int` indices in the range 0..w-1, 0..h-1. If you pass `float`s they will be truncated to `int`s (it's better to convert explicitly), but in any case the indices should not be negative. If you have `u_img == -28.672` it means your `u` is not in the range 0..1 as expected.

Comment: What is width, what is height? Are they uninitialized?